# Callers say they can hardly hear me when talking on my iPhone 7

Tags: iphone

When I am on the phone with a caller, they say they can hardly hear me. My volume is high and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Is it in a case? Try taking it out.

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to check Bluetooth, headset speakerphone and normal receiver function.

If the volume is bad on all, look to software restore or work with the carrier.

If not and assuming you're not having problems with recording videos etc, and this is only happening during a normal phone call (that is, not on speakerphone).

If so, one test you can do is to open the Voice Memos app and record yourself speaking into it. I would record maybe 10 seconds of yourself speaking and then play it back. You should be able to hear yourself clearly.

If not, this could indicate a hardware problem, but before jumping to that conclusion there are other things to try:

- restart your iPhone
- Remove any case and/or screen protector you're using
- Unplug any accessories you have connected to the headphone jack
- Remove any dirt/dust that could be blocking the microphone

If none of these help, I would contact Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I had my phone in my shirt pocket and forgot I had some chocolate in it also. The chocolate had melted and got into the mic's. So....check your mic's ( The row of small circular openings across the bottom of the phone.)